# Unable to apply MarginalImputer

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import sage 
model = CatBoostClassifier(iterations=50,learning_rate=0.3,depth=3)
model = model.fit(train, Y_train, categorical_inds, eval_set=(val, Y_val),verbose=False)

imputer = sage.MarginalImputer(model, train[:512])
estimator = sage.PermutationEstimator(imputer, 'cross entropy')
```

I am wondering why it return `module 'sage' has no attribute 'MarginalImputer'` despite everything is fine?

Comment: What version of sage are you using?

Comment: i check and it says 0.0.0

Comment: Are you sure? 0.0.0 doesn't sound like a real version. To be clear, the package that you seem to be using is `sage-importance`, please correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Comment: when i install using `pip install sage` it shows `Successfully installed sage-0.0.0`. May i know how to get the correct version of SAGE?

Comment: Then I think you're installing the wrong package. Google "python sage" and check which sage you want to use. To me it seems you're looking for `sage-importance`, as I can see the `MarginalImputer` attribute being used here: https://github.com/iancovert/sage

Comment: thank you. I have reinstalled and refreshed my notebook and it runs prefectly